# How do I define an anonymous recursive function?

Tags: haskell

One can define an anonymous function with a lambda expression:

```
-- Contrived example
> apply f x = f x
> apply (\n -> n + 1) 3
4
```

but is it possible to define an anonymous *recursive* function?

```
> apply (\n -> n * ??? (n - 1)) 3 -- compute a factorial
6
```

Answer (score 3):

Import `Data.Function` and use the `fix` function to compute the fixed point of a *non*-recursive function that takes the function to apply recursively as an argument

```
> import Data.Function
> :t fix
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
> apply (fix $ \f n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * f (n - 1)) 3
6
```